# Счётчик внутри класса(Python)

Tags: python, классы, counter

Доброго времени суток :)

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, а лучше объясните на пальцах.

Необходимо реализовать счётчик внутри класса, да и не обязательно внутри класса, но чтобы он работал в зависимости от количества обращенний к классу.

Пример следующий:

```
class Coordinates:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.count += 1

    def print_info(self):
        print(
            f'X: {self.x}\n'
            f'Y: {self.y}\n'
            f'Кол-во точек: {self.count}\n'
        )


coord_1 = Coordinates(10, 20)
coord_1.print_info()
coord_2 = Coordinates(15, 30)
coord_2.print_info()
```

Информация на выходе:

```
X: 10
Y: 20
Кол-во точек: 1

X: 15
Y: 30
Кол-во точек: 1
```

Понимаю что, я где-то что-то не дописал, но что именно не понимаю :(

Заранее спасибо

P.S.: Перечитал 10 раз свой вопрос, знаю что он глупый, но что-то самому никак не получается додуматься что с этим делать. Понимаю что по моему примеру счетчик всегда будет равен "1", так как каждый раз идёт обращение к классу где счетчик равен "0"

Comment: `self.count += 1` -> `Coordinates.count += 1`

Comment: спасибо большое :)
честно говоря стыдно что сам не додумался :')

Comment: Честно говоря, получился хрупкий код: если вы переименуете класс, код развалится. Нечаянно можно поменять поле в другом классе (при программировании методом copy/paste). Вот так можно избежать упоминания имени класса: `type(self).count += 1`.

Comment: Очень изящно, обращение к самому себе не по имени а по типу. Возьму на вооружение, думаю в будущем пригодится ни раз :) большое спасибо :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужен некого рода счётчик обращения к классу
Вот код:

```
class Coordinates:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        Coordinates.count +=1
    
    def print_info(self):
        print(
            f'X: {self.x}\n'
            f'Y: {self.y}\n'
            f'Кол-во точек: {self.count}\n'
        )


coord_1 = Coordinates(10, 20)
coord_1.print_info()
coord_2 = Coordinates(15, 30)
coord_2.print_info()
```

Почему ваш вариант не работает ? Потому-что каждый раз при обращении классу вы заново инициализируете переменную **count** Что-бы вынести это на глобальный уровень, вам нужно обратиться к переменной внутри класса через имя класса. Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: Да, теперь всё встало на свои места :)
Спасибо большое за уделённое время :)

Comment: Ваша формулировка не совсем точная. Переменная `count` не инициализируется при инстанциировании объекта, а новый объект **получает копию переменной класса** `count`, в классе эта переменная всегда =0 (там её никто не меняет после инициализации), поэтому получается вот так. Инициализируется эта переменная всего один раз - во время определения самого класса.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы жестко не привязываться к имени класса можно обратиться к атрибуту класса через classmethod. Примерно так:

```
class Coordinates:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.c()

    def print_info(self):
        print(
            f'X: {self.x}\n'
            f'Y: {self.y}\n'
            f'Кол-во точек: {self.count}\n'
        )

    @classmethod
    def c(cls):
        cls.count+=1
```